# Checkboxes in rails returning no value? How to get Checkboxes working with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox, null

I am trying to get the values from my check boxes, but whenever I use params[:chosen], it seems to always return nil. What am I missing? is params the right way to do it?

This is the line I have in my view:

```
<td><%= check_box_tag "chosen[#{i}]",i,true,:name => "chosen[]" %></td>
```

this does produce the checkboxes but I can never seem to get the value from it. Do I need to put something in the controller?

Thank you

Comment: Are you certain this is within the form that you are submitting? Are you checking the boxes? The value of the check box won't automatically get updated.

Comment: How would i update the value of the check boxes? I Have an update button but how could i make it so that when it is clicked, only the checked boxes come up. Also what do you mean by "within the form you are submitting"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the :name => "chosen[]". The first argument is already used as the name. Also, the Rails guides recommend always using a label_tag wtih check_box_tag

```
<td>
<%= label_tag :my_attribute, "Attribute Label" %>
<%= check_box_tag :my_attribute, my_model.my_attribute %>
</td>
```

then the controller can check params[:my_attribute]

Comment: So the controller can check params[:chosen]? How do i get the value in the view? Am i supposed to put something in the controller for the checkboxes?

Comment: Also, i took out the :name => "chosen[]" part and put in the label_tag, but still the value is nil

Comment: This might explain your problem. Read the section in the docs on  ActionView::Helpers::FormHelper#check_box at http://api.rubyonrails.org/ under the heading Gotcha.

Answer (score 0):

`<%= f.check_box :hobby, {:multiple => "true"}, "hockeys", nil %>Hockey`

`<%= f.check_box :hobby, {:multiple => "true"}, "cricket", nil %>cricket`

This will be very much helpful to you.